Using starts_with for comparing a string to a list of strings in Polars
Could I do a starts_with check for a string with a list of strings and return True if the string starts with any of the strings in the list.
For now, I came up with the following.
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'a': ['https://abcd.com', 'https://youtube.com'], 
    'validation_urls': [
        ['https://abcd.com', 'https://efgh.com'], 
        ['https://abcd.com', 'https://efgh.com']
    ],
})

df = df.with_columns(is_valid=pl.col('a').str.starts_with(pl.col('validation_urls').explode()))

┌─────────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ a                   ┆ validation_urls                          ┆ is_valid │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                                      ┆ ---      │
│ str                 ┆ list[str]                                ┆ bool     │
╞═════════════════════╪══════════════════════════════════════════╪══════════╡
│ https://abcd.com    ┆ ["https://abcd.com", "https://efgh.com"] ┆ true     │
│ https://youtube.com ┆ ["https://abcd.com", "https://efgh.com"] ┆ false    │
└─────────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────┘

However, I am not sure if this is the ideal way to perform this check.

The code looks incorrect to me - if you reverse the validation_urls, the first row also returns false.

There is .str.contains_any (https://docs.pola.rs/api/python/stable/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.str.contains_any.html) but no .str.starts_with_any. is_valid=pl.col("a").str.contains_any(pl.col("validation_urls").explode())

Is validation_urls really a single list? Or is supposed to be a "row based" comparison with different possible validation_urls on each row?

it is row based, each row will have separate validation_urls, the length of the list would also differ


.concat_list() to add a column as a first element to the list.
list.eval() to check whether any of list elements starts with first element.
list.slice() to remove first element from the list.
list.any() to check whether there any match.

df.with_columns(
    is_valid = 
    pl.concat_list(pl.col.a, pl.col.validation_urls)
    .list.eval(pl.element().first().str.starts_with(pl.element()))
    .list.slice(1)
    .list.any()
)

┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│ a                   ┆ validation_urls                 ┆ is_valid │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                             ┆ ---      │
│ str                 ┆ list[str]                       ┆ bool     │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════════════════╪══════════╡
│ https://abcd.com    ┆ ["https://abcd.com", "https://… ┆ true     │
│ https://youtube.com ┆ ["https://abcd.com", "https://… ┆ false    │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────────┴──────────┘

Alternatively

explode() to unpack string lists.
group_by() to aggregate data back.

(
    df
    .explode("validation_urls")
    .with_columns(is_valid = pl.col.a.str.starts_with(pl.col.validation_urls))
    .group_by("a")
    .agg(
        pl.col.validation_urls,
        pl.col.is_valid.any()
    )
)


In your first approach, the first() should probably be moved to the first pl.element() call, right?

ah true, thanks, I'll adjust the answer
